# React native share API - problems when both message and url used

Tags: react-native, share, message

We are implementing share functionality in our react native app and I'm having difficulty with the appearance of the resulting share text.

Using the share API, if i set just the `URL` param to our website and share via sms the result looks great.  I have set the image and title meta tags and they render in the sms as expected (ie I get a nice picture).  However, if I want to add a dynamic message to the share text, via the `message` param it looks awful. I get 2 sms, one with a text link to the site (no image, no title), then a second sms with the message text. For reference, I am aiming for something in appearance to what you get when you share an app in iOS, like this:

[image: What I want]

But sharing just a URL via share I get this:

[image: Just URL]

which looks nice, with image etc but no dynamic text.

As soon as i add some text via the `message` param, the result looks like this:

[image: URL and message]

which looks pretty crappy.

It kind of feels like this is a pretty vanilla use case and i can't see what I'm doing wrong.  Anyone got any ideas?

Edit: A simplified version of the code I'm using is as follows:

```
import { Share } from 'react-native'

const content = {
      message: 'This is a lovely message',
      url: 'https://www.google.com/chrome/'
    }

try {
      const result = await Share.share(content)
      console.log('Shared', result)

      if (result.action === Share.sharedAction) {
        // shared
      } else if (result.action === Share.dismissedAction) {
        // IOS ONLY
        // dismissed
      }
    } catch (err) {
      console.log('Failed to share', err)
    }
  }
```

Comment: Please create a [mcve]

Comment: @Tim added some simple example code